# How to read latest file from Adls, not last modified file. File name eg(xxxxx_202210,xxxxx_202211)

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

Want to load latest filename(xxxx_202210,xxxx_202211) in this case 2nd file, from Adls to Sql.
and if file is already there delete it using pre copy script.

I have used get meta data activity to get the child items, and then used for each loop to iterate and used if condtion, and in if condition used the greater function  by using substring on file name and comparing it with a refrence variable. and then 2 set variable to assign values, not sure why it is giving different results.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

These are my sample source files list in the above format from Get Meta data activity.

[image]

Give this array to a **ForEach activity**. create an **array variable** with default value and inside ForEach use append variable.

Use the below expression in the append to get the Date as integer array.

```
@int(substring(item().name, add(indexof(item().name,'_'),1),6))
```

[image]

Next, get the maximum out of that array and the file which has this number will be a latest file according to the file name. Store this in a string variable.

```
@string(max(variables('month_array')))
```

[image]

Then use copy activity and in the wild card path use the below expression.

```
@concat('*',variables('maxdate'),'.csv')
```

[image]

**Target table in SQL:**

[image]